# Mixpanel tracking from server caching

Tags: c#, azure, mixpanel

This is a general design question.  I'm currently sending tracking events from my server (C# web api hosted on azure) to Mixpanel (using Mixpanel.NET package: https://github.com/chrisnicola/Mixpanel.NET).

This works fine for the most part.  However, it's not as robust as I'd like it:
1. while minimal, it's unnecessarily slowing down my server because the events are being sent during normal usage of the API.
2. if mixpanel goes down, the events are lost

What's the best way to address these concerns?  I was thinking I could cache the events on my server and eventually send them to Mixpanel.  Is that a good approach?  Guessing I'd need to use some type of durable storage in case my server goes down before sending them.  Would azure queues be good for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Depending on size of message you could write them to either an [Azure Storage Queue](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) or [Azure Service Bus](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/). If your message is too large to go on the queue on its own you could just write a stub record to the queue and then actually write the full message to either [Azure Table Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/), [Azure SQL Database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) or [Azure DocumentDB](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/) using the queue stub as a way to identify where the full message is stored.
2. Use a [Worker Role to read the queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj149831.aspx) and send messages to the Mixpanel API. When Mixpanel is down simply don't pop the stub from the queue and it will get re-processed. If the Mixpanel API is up, use the stub to pull the full message and send to the Mixpanel API and then remove the stub from the queue.